# Fill remaining space but also have buttons snapped to bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

On my form I have a label, a multi-line text box and some buttons. I wish to have the buttons snapped to the bottom of the activity and the multi-line text box fill the remaining space.

The only way I can get the buttons to snap to the bottom is using android:layout_alignParentBottom on the container which means the main layout has to be Relative.

However, the only way I can get the multi-line text box to fill the space is if the container is a linearlayout and use 0dp/weight=1.

The include at the bottom is simply a horizontal linearlayout with buttons.

Is there a way to do this? As below I've tried using Table Rows, etc too. Screenshot below of how it looks now.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/fragmentBackdropPlain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttonText"
            android:text="@string/subtopic_content_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableRow>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editSubTopicContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:hint="@string/subtopic_content_hint"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/include_edit_buttons" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/fragmentBackdropPlain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/buttons">

    <include layout="@layout/include_edit_buttons" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttons">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttonText"
        android:text="@string/subtopic_content_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableRow>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editSubTopicContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:hint="@string/subtopic_content_hint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Explanation:
The difference is that now he first creates the Buttons. After creating the buttons, you can use `fill_parent` for the height of the other layout (linearLayout1) and he will use the space that is left. If you write it the other way round, he first inflates the linearLayout1. Since the layout is still empty, `fill_parent` will take the whole place. And then there is no place left for the Buttons.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. How does declaring the buttons above make it work? I just assumed to place them in the order I wanted and that telling the items to go above/below/relative to another would not matter what order in the XML you do it?

Comment: @Neil I have added an explanation in the answer!

Comment: Ah, cheers, I never thought of that. Now I know it should all make a lot more sense when I get other issues with layout :)